# c# Use ressource image in html code

Tags: c#, html

I need to send outside E-Mail with outlook, the body is in html, it's work fine excep i try to use an image include in my ressource and it's not working.

My code :

```
var Logo = Properties.Resources.Logo;
oMsg.HTMLBody = oMsg.HTMLBody + "<img src = \"" + Logo + "\">";
```

no error but no image also !  Someone can help me on that ?

Thanks

Here new information :

Here is my new code :

```
    public static byte[] ExtractResource(Bitmap image)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    if (ms == null)
        return null;
    byte[] imageByteArray = ms.ToArray();
    return imageByteArray;
}
private static string Base64FromByteArray(byte[] image)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(image);
}
```

and the call is :

```
        String imgBase64 = Base64FromByteArray(ExtractResource(Properties.Resources.Logo));

    oMsg.HTMLBody = oMsg.HTMLBody + "<table><td><img src = \"data:image/jpeg;base64," + imgBase64 + "\" /></td></table>";
```

No error, but still no Logo in my mail !! Someone see an error in my code ?

Comment: what is the value of `Logo`? Is the email sent in html or plain text? Please check the [mcve] help page.

Comment: Logo is a jpeg image, and is html content for the e-mail

Comment: I did as for the actual value of the variable, not a description. Check toadflakz's answer and, if it helps you, marks is as answered/helpful

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a Base64-encoded image inline in the IMG tag of your HTML body using the data URL scheme.

From [Embed BASE64-Encoded Images Inline In HTML](http://www.bigfastblog.com/embed-base64-encoded-images-inline-in-html)

> `<img src=”data:<MIMETYPE>;base64,<BASE64_ENCODED_IMAGE>”>`
>
> `<img src=”data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS… (see source for full base64  encoded image) …8bgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=”>`

Other useful links from the above link:

[RFC2397 - The "data" URI Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397)

[Wikipedia - Data URI Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)